# regexp get everything up to the first number/integer from drop down selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, integer

I have a drop down list and I want to take the selected value and get the string up to and not including the first integer.

e.g. ASPX

```
<a href="#" title="Do you require a particular room? If so select here">Room Number</a><!-- ROOM NUMBER -->
<asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="roomNumDDL1" title="For room 1" runat="server" style="width:80px;"></asp:DropDownList>
```

How would I get this value C# side. The example string would be A203, or CC0123b.

Would it be something like this...

```
string buildingCode = roomNumDDL1.SelectedValue.Split(new char[] {^.*(?=(\[0-9])} )[1];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
string buildingCode = Regex.Match(roomNumDDL1.SelectedValue, @"^.*?(?=\d)");
```

- `^`: match from the start of the string
- `.*?`: match any character, zero or more times (`.*`), but as few times as possible (`?`)
- `?=\d)` until the next character is a digit (`\d`)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^0-9]*
```

Start at the beginning of the string, then match any number of characters that aren't digits.